# Parameterize datetime in vega-lite

Tags: vega-lite, vega

I am trying to plot a simple line graph of temperature vs. time.

I am trying to make a parameter (e.g. slider) for the datetime (to determine range), but I cannot get a parameter to work with a datetime type. I instead put the year, month, and day as separate (integer) parameters:

```json
  "params": [
    {
      "name": "lowYear",
      "value": 2021,
      "bind": {"input": "range", "min": 2020, "max": 2022, "step": 1}
    },
    {
      "name": "lowMonth",
      "value": 1,
      "bind": {"input": "range", "min": 1, "max": 12, "step": 1}
    },
    {
      "name": "lowDay",
      "value": 1,
      "bind": {"input": "range", "min": 1, "max": 31, "step": 1}
    }
]
```

I can apply a filter on the date time easily, but this fails when I use an expression for these values.

```json
  "transform": [
    {
      "filter": {
        "field": "timestamp",
        "gte": {"year": 2021, "month": 2, "date": 20}
      }
    }
  ]
```

But this fails:

```json
  "transform": [
    {
      "filter": {
        "field": "timestamp",
        "gte": {"year": {"expr": "lowYear"}, "month": 2, "date": 20}
      }
    }
  ]
```

It seems that filters can take expressions, but maybe not when nested in `datetime`s. Is this the case? How can I parametize a datetime?

Comment: What does this have to do with clojure?

Comment: I was originally showing sample code using Oz, a clojure vega-lite library

Comment: Ah ok. Just be careful if you leave the tag after deleting the code. Veteran users here typically follow tags and clogging our feeds with stuff unrelated to our interests is unfortunate (also doesn't help you get an answer!). I see you removed the clojure tag, all good.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are still looking for an answer to this, but I had a similar problem which I have now solved.

My problem involved getting the scale of the x-axis to represent a whole 12 months, even if no data existed in, for example, December, based on the Year selected from a range control.

`scale: {"domain" :[{"expr":"datetime(AnnualPeriod,0,1)"},{"expr":"datetime(AnnualPeriod,11,31)"}]}`

where "AnnualPeriod" is the data field bound to the range control

`"params": [{"name" : "AnnualPeriod", "value": 2019,"bind" : {"input": "range", "min":1995, "max":2020,"step":1}}],`

and the data is filtered by year using this filter:

`transform:[{"filter":"year(datum.date_of_transfer)===AnnualPeriod"}],`

The bit that I think will help you is:

`{"expr":"datetime(AnnualPeriod,0,1)"}`

where **AnnualPeriod** is equivalent to your **lowYear** and the month is **0** for **January** and **1** is the **1st**.

so yours should read:

`"gte": {"expr":"datetime(lowYear,1,20)"}`

Note the zero based array for months.  1 = Feb.